# Pass FormControl to a child that has a child that uses ControlValueAccessor in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm developing a Mobile App using Ionic + **Angular** using ReactiveForms.

I have a base `input-form-control` component that I use across the application. This component implements `ControlValueAccessor` and facilitate the process.

*I will show short snippets of the code to explain the idea...*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-form-control',
  templateUrl: './input-form-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-form-control.component.scss']
})
export class InputFormControlComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, DoCheck { }
```

Example of use from a parent:

```
<app-input-form-control formControlName="test">
</app-input-form-control>
```

**All good so far.**

Now, I have a requirement to add more functionality to an input. Let's say by adding a button below it to open a modal, choose a phone number from a list and add it as the value of the input.

For me, this is a new component that can be used across the app. Let's create it to explain my issue:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-number-form-control',
  templateUrl: './phone-number-form-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-number-form-control.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneNumberFormControlComponent {
  
  constructor(
    public ngControl: NgControl
  ) {
  }
  
}
```

I know that I need and input, which I have already (remember the previous base input that I've shown) and a button below it.

./phone-number-form-control.component.html

```
// This is my base input from before
<app-input-form-control
   [(ngModel)]="ngControl"> // Note here...
</app-input-form-control>

// This is the new requirement of the feature
<ion-button>Open modal</ion-button>
```

Example of use:

```
<app-phone-number-form-control
         formControlName="phoneNumber">
</app-phone-number-form-control>
```

I received:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name:
> 'phoneNumber'

I don't know how to pass the FormControl from `app-phone-number-form-control` to `app-input-form-control`.

I have tried to follow other topics that talks about this, but they only reached until the creation of `app-input-form-control`. In my case, I have another component as an intermediate.

My goal is to be able to create a component that uses my base input (app-input-form-control) and pass it the FormControl.

Comment: The way we solve this in our project is by creating our own custom `FormParent` component which holds the reference to the `FormGroup` Each component which is compatible with a `FormParent` optionally injects it in its constructor and registers itself in the FormGroup. The disadvantage is pretty tightly coupled components, but it does make it fast.

Comment: @MikkelChristensen Seems interesting. Don't know how to structure correctly the FormParent. If you have time, can you share a short, basic example to implement the technique? Will help a lot.